# Using ocsp stapling in Android to verify certificate

Tags: android, ssl, ocsp

I would like to verify (on enabled servers) the server certificate on HTTPS connections.

My problem is I understood how it works, but I cannot find a reference implementation for Android. I was already thinking about to add that TLS extension to the handshake myself, but I found also in that direction nothing.

If there is someone experienced with that topic, I would be very happy about some pointers with best practices in the right direction.